# Struts2: Pass parameter to the action class does not work

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, struts2

I am using struts 2.3.24

I wanted to pass some parameter to the action class. Here is my link.

```xml
<a id = "errorOid" 
 type = "submit"
 href = "<s:url action="SortIssue"><s:param name="sortField" value="ISSUE_OID"/></s:url>">
    Error Oid
</a>
```

When I click on the link it goes to the action method, but the sortField always comes null.

Here is my action:

```xml
<action name="SortIssue" method="sortIssue" class="foo.bar.IssueAction">
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/issue.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/issue.jsp</result>
    <result name="login" type="redirectAction">Login</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="user-submit" />
</action>
```

This is the method which is called when click on the link.

```java
public String sortIssue() throws ServiceFatalException,ServiceExpectedException{
        Log.error(this,"################## inside sort ###################"+sortField);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

My question is :

How to get the parameter passed from the jsp?

Also is it possible to get the hidden parameter after click on the link?

Note: Passing the parameter stuff works fine when I use it inside the iterator.

Comment: Try to use single quotes where ever text is already wrapped in double quotes. Normally struts 2 framework automatically gets the value of a field ( only presented by struts 2 tag ) if accessible setter and getters are defined in the action class for the property

Comment: And I don't think hidden field value shall be passed if you click on a link. Such fields are passed only if you submit the form

Comment: Use quotes to indicate that this is a string.

Comment: @SacJn : Yes. I need to change the css of submit button to look like command link (anchor), to make it work.

Comment: @Andrea Ligios : I have a table, where for each header I have put the sorting functionality. I need to get the old sorting (sortBy and sortOrder) as well as new sortBy. By passing the parameter I can get the new sortBy. So if I want the old sorting, I need to keep that as hidden and changed the anchor tag by submit button. I changed the submit button's css to make it look similar to anchor tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [Tag Syntax documentation](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/tag-syntax#value-is-an-object):

> ## value is an Object!
>
> Most often, the value attribute is set automatically, since name attribute usually tells the framework which property to call to set the value. But, if there is a reason to set the value directly, be advised that **value is an Object NOT a String**.
> (warning) Since value is not a String, whatever is passed to value is
> evaluated as an expression - **NOT** a String literal.
>
> ## Probably wrong!
>
> ```xml
> <s:textfield key="state.label" name="state" value="ca"/>
> ```
>
> If a textfield is passed the value attribute "ca", the framework will look for a property named `getCa()`. Generally, this is not what we mean.
> What we mean to do is pass a literal String. In the expression language, literals are placed within quotes
>
> ## Passing a literal value the right way
>
> ```xml
> <s:textfield key="state.label" name="state" value="%{'ca'}" />
> ```
>
> Another approach would be to use the idiom `value="'ca'"`, but, in
> this case, using the expression notation is recommended.
>
> [...]

This means that when you write `value="ISSUE_OID"`, Struts searches for objects named `ISSUE_OID` in the Value Stack, for methods `getISSUE_OID()` in the Action, etc...

If you want to pass a String literal, you can use `value="%{'ISSUE_OID'}"`, or
place your value in the HTML body of the tag, because HTML body is not evaluated and everything you put there becomes a String.

Then in your case:

```xml
<s:param name="sortField" value="%{'ISSUE_OID'}"/>
```

or

```xml
<s:param name="sortField">ISSUE_OID</param>
```

Comment: `%{` isn't really needed here since it is already evaluated. +1 for quoting official docs.

Comment: I almost never use it when doing this, but... :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Is it possible to get the hidden parameter after click on the link?

Comment: Everything is possible, sky's the limit :) But this seems like another question (and BTW I dont' see any hidden parameter in this one)

Comment: @Unknown What "hidden parameter"? You're not submitting a form, you're clicking a link.

Comment: @Dave Newton  Thanks. I used <s:submit> for each sort field and changed its css to look like anchor tag, so that I could get the hidden parameter. I will post my answer tomorrow.

Comment: With your answer you mean your question ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios You save my times:) +1

Comment: @Andrea Ligios : Exactly. Sky is the limit :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<s:url id="errorOid" action="sortIssue">
   <s:param name="sortField">ISSUE_OID</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{errorOid}">Error Oid</s:a>
```

For more understanding about `param`,see below

**case 1**

```
<s:param name="sortField">ISSUE_OID</s:param>
```

The value evaluates to the value stack as a **java.lang.String** object

**case 2**

```
<s:param name="sortField" value="ISSUE_OID"></s:param>
```

The value evaluates to the value stack as a **java.lang.Objec**t object.
For details info check [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-808).

Comment: No no no. Edit ruined everything.

Comment: @Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye: Could you change to  <s:param name="sortField">ISSUE_OID</s:param>

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye: Can you explain why it isn't working in OP case?

Comment: @AleksandrM Sure. But now I back from my office. Later I have times, I will edit my answer. If you have times, please explain OP and post your answer. Thanks dude.

Comment: Looks like a shot in the dark. No cookie for you.

Comment: @AleksandrM I'm sorry I spoiled it :P